# How to get email address from a webview?

Tags: iphone, ios, string

My question is how can I get an email address if my UIWebView is loaded...

First I made a string about the View and I could find @ in my string with this:

```
NSString *myText = [mWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.textContent"];
if ([myText rangeOfString:@"@"].location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't find mail address!");

}

else {
    NSLog(@"There is a valid mail address!");
}
```

But I don't know how to get the content around this ( *@*) to a var.

Comment: So if I enter for an email address "richard@test.com" what data do you need out of it?

Comment: My webview has an adress on a webpage. My question is how to get it to a variable!

Comment: Currently, what is 'myText' printing out as then?

Comment: use webView delegate methods for this

Comment: Currently printing out road properties text with contact datas and other usefull information.

Comment: Did you try a regular expression? (Reguláris kifejeztést próbáltál?)

Comment: Have you tried printing the output of `myText`. Once you are sure that the text is working fine, you should then proceed to use an `NSPredicate` to find the address.

Comment: How is NSPredicate locate that address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```
NSString *myText = [www stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML;"];
NSString *expression = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSError *error = NULL;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:myText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [myText length])];

if (match){
    NSString *email = [myText substringWithRange:match.range];
    NSLog(@"There is a valid mail address: %@", email);
}else{
    NSLog(@"Couldn't find mail address!");
}
```

Comment: But I have to ask you something again! I have a WebView and a button on the bottom of it to start the mail composer. I pasted the 'match' to my mail sender code to the 'setRecipients' segment of it. I want to senf a mail to the mail addresses on my WebView. So if I press the button it starts my mail composer with the address from WebView.    The problem is when I dont have any mail address on WV the mail composer starts with a blank recipients field. But if I have an address on WV its quit with an exception...dont know why...............

Comment: So I dont know how to insert it as a result to mail composer! Please help!

Comment: To get the email address, use this in the match loop  NSString *email = [myText substringWithRange:match.range];